# Display numbers in characters as integers

Tags: java, arrays

```
int value = 1234;
char[] chars = String.valueOf(value).toCharArray();
```

How would I display those value as integers?

Comment: If you want to get an array of individual digits, use a loop, division and mod operators

Comment: I just wanna get the min and max values of the number Sequencewhich User input.
Just like:

Comment: @OliverQueen You mean the minimum and maximum digits of the input. For instance, for value = 1234, it will be 1 and 4? Right?

Comment: I just wanna print min and max values of a sequence from the user input
Just like if I input 12345 then Max:5 and Min:1....

Comment: consider the ascii value of '1'

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 1234;
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (value > 0) {
        output.add(value % 10);
        value /= 10;
    }
    Collections.sort(output);
    System.out.println("Min:" + output.get(0));
    System.out.println("Max:" + output.get(output.size() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. You are missing an important piece though. You need to call `sort()` on `Arrays`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 1234;
    char[] arr = String.valueOf(value).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
}
```

O/P :

```
1 4 // arr[0] is min and arr[arr.length-1] is max
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using for loop ,only if you want to display these numbers seperately.I suggest you want to display all four digits in seperate four lines.it will be done by bellow code.

```
 int value = 1234;
 char [] chars = String.valueOf(value).toCharArray();     
 for(int i=0; i < chars.length ; i++ )
 System.out.println(chars[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop to pull of each individual digit and compare it to the current min/max :

```
int n = 36348;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    if (n > 0) {


        while (n > 0) {
            int digit = n % 10;

            max = Math.max(max, digit);
            min = Math.min(min, digit);

            n /= 10;
        }


    }

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(max);
```